# Navbar's dropdown menu not showing after the length of the navbar in main page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this weird issue with my navbar. I did use a template that I got online, I will say.
The issue at hand is that on the main page, the dropdown menu does not extend fully and only goes as far as the length of the actual navigation bar (Check the image below).
I tried altering the Z-index of the dropdown menu but that did not work either. I will share the HTML of the navbar here but will attach the CSS files as hyperlinks as they are too long.

For the CSS files for styles.css and navstyles.css:
https://anonpaste.pw/v/4248bb4b-4d29-42b9-8953-7e634d4ff3d6#qfuoKsJDiwyB44bX31ML-GmA2V5Mqam4w6iDsSvcZ3k

For index.html (the main file): https://anonpaste.pw/v/01329dd9-5935-457e-aad2-f2b5233b8a03#nQWcD9amGmUIrPzZWPfq_fC98HwL8amCcbmgWcJJ4og

I had to use these two sites because pastebin is not allowed on my network.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  {% load static %}
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'food/fonts/icomoon/style.css' %}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'food/css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'food/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

  <!-- Style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'food/css/navstyle.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'food/css/style.css' %}">
  <style>
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999; /* Increase the value */
    background-color: #fff; /* Set a background color */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a border for visibility */
}

    .rounded-container {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 8px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
  </style>
  <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="site-mobile-menu site-navbar-target">
    <div class="site-mobile-menu-header">
      <div class="site-mobile-menu-close mt-3">
        <span class="icon-close2 js-menu-toggle"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-mobile-menu-body"></div>
  </div>

  <header class="site-navbar js-sticky-header site-navbar-target" role="banner">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center position-relative">


        <div class="site-logo">
          <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="text-black"><span class="text-primary">Royal Taj</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">
          <nav class="site-navigation text-right ml-auto " role="navigation">

            <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav ml-auto d-none d-lg-block">
              <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="nav-link {% if active_link == 'index' %}active{% endif %}">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'food:order' %}" class="nav-link {% if active_link == 'order' %}active{% endif %}">
                  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/30/shopping-cart--v2.png" class="logo"><span
                    id="cart">0</span></a></li>




                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'food:profile' %}"
                      class="nav-link {% if active_link == 'profile' %}active{% endif %}">Profile</a></li>
                      {% endif %}
              <li class="has-children">
                <a class="nav-link">Food Categories</a>
                <ul class="dropdown arrow-top">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item {% if active_link == 'starters' %}active{% endif %}"
                    href="{% url 'food:starters' %}">Starters</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item {% if active_link == 'rice' %}active{% endif %}"
                    href="{% url 'food:rice' %}">Rice</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item {% if active_link == 'chicken' %}active{% endif %}"
                    href="{% url 'food:chicken' %}">Chicken Main</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a class="nav-link {% if active_link == 'support' %}active{% endif %}"
                href="{% url 'food:support' %}">Support / FAQs</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link {% if active_link == 'about_us' %}active{% endif %}"
                href="{% url 'food:about_us' %}">About Us</a></li>

            </ul>
          </nav>

        </div>

        <div class="toggle-button d-inline-block d-lg-none"><a href="#"
            class="site-menu-toggle py-5 js-menu-toggle text-black"><span class="icon-menu h3"></span></a></div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </header>
</body>


  {% block content %} {% endblock %}
  <script src="{% static 'food/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'food/js/jquery.sticky.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'food/js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'food/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'food/js/nav.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'food/js/main.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  


</html>
```

Here is what the issue actually looks like:
[image: Navbar's dropdown not loading properly]

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the fix to the question I asked.
The issue was in the index.html file where I had set the overflow for header as hidden. Removing that fixed the issue.